# Seek bar's draggable thumb

Tags: android

I want not to be able to move the draggable thumb of my seek bar. `progressBar.setClickable(false);` does not help.

Comment: I will answer my own question. `progressBar.setEnabled(false);` helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) is not clickable by default so you can use it instead of [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html). If you want to disable SeekBar thumb use

```
progressBar.setEnabled(false);
```